# Why is my .NET application generating so many page faults?

Tags: .net, performance, memory, paging

I have a 64-bit .NET console application that basically reads messages from MSMQ and then process them by communicating with SQL server via the .NET SqlClient.  Most of the time it works fine, but every now and then gets itself into a state where everything, even the simplest operations, such as building up a SqlCommand parameter array, runs abnormally slowly.  In worst case scenarios the application does nothing at all for 30 minutes at a time (nothing written to the logs, and it's quite chatty with verbose mode on), then will start writing again, with no indication of what caused the delay.  This has serious impacts on the usability of our product.

I've spent the last few hours looking at every single performance counter etc., and everything points to excessive page reads - it's maxing out on Disk I/O due to this, I can see my process constantly reading heavily from pagefile.sys etc. etc. But I have no idea why, because the total memory usage for the application is well below the available RAM: working set is 60M, total commit size is 300M (high, and matching the peak working set - not sure why this is), but that's peanuts compared to the 12 Gig of RAM available, of which very little else is being used.

I've read through every single MS document about monitoring application performance etc., but everything just points to "my application needs more memory".  Ok...so how do it give it more memory - nothing else is using it!  Now there's a separate issue that given what the application does, it really shouldn't need that much memory anyway, but the effort it would take to get that down is probably not worth the cost of more hardware.

One other thing to note: if I start a second instance of the same application, it seems to run fine.  So it's obviously not a system-wide problem.

I've seen a few similar posts here on stackoverflow but no particularly helpful answers yet...hoping for more luck than previous posters.

Comment: Have you tried profiling the program during these ultra slow periods and seeing what methods it is spending the most time in? Visual Studio has a really good profiler

Comment: What else is going on in the system?  Do you have other CPU-intensive processes going on?  Where is the SQL Server database running?  How many messages does this console application process per minute?  There is so much that could be in your environment causing the problem...  Using the Visual Studio debugger and attaching to the process during those slow times would be a good start.  Is the code small enough that you could provide some examples of the core logic as a [Pastie](http://pastie.org/) for example?

Comment: Yes, I've tried everything - it's not doing anything that it doesn't do all the time.  There's nothing else on the system that's using any CPU or memory.  Sql server is elsewhere.  I am wondering whether the high page faulting is necessarily relevant, as I just looked at all disk i/o for that process, and it's actually doing a lot more *writing* to the MSMQ storage area (and why writing - this process doesn't even generate messages, only removes them?) than it is reading from pagefile.sys

Comment: What is the load on the queue?  Does the application stay consistently ahead of the queue, or is there ever a backlog?

Comment: There's a huge backlog - 50000 messages at least.  The clients are written to throttle back when it gets too big, but the bottleneck shouldn't be happening.  This might be relevant: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/897326 but it doesn't really explain why other simple non-MSMQ-related operations start running so slowly, nor does it explain why a second instance of the application is able to run fine.

Comment: So the problem occurs before the backlog, and leads to the backlog, or the other way around?  This may be relevant: http://serverfault.com/questions/110143/msmq-very-slow-to-receive-messages.  And this looks interesting as well - http://serverfault.com/questions/272242/msmq-write-taking-1-minute.  During the slow times, could you use some sort of GUI tool to try reading/writing messages to the queue and see if it's relatively fast?  You may have some sort of network configuration issue - 30-second timeuots with a network problem can add up really fast.

Comment: The problem leads to the backlog. Might even be some sort of vicious circle...

Comment: What are the specs on the Hardware hosting the queue?  Is it good and fast, like an SSD or a RAID array?  I'm not that familiar with MSMQ, but it looks like some configurations can lead to random I/O per message read/sent (see http://ayende.com/blog/4251/what-am-i-missing-msmq-perf-issue), which could cause a lot of thrashing and cache misses.  Are there remote processes on other machines in the network that would be causing I/O on the same drive?  I.e., is it a shared network drive or SAN?

Comment: Right now it seems to be chugging away ok, with relatively low reads/sec from pagefile.sys, but quite high writes to the msmq storage area.  The slowness definitely seems related to high reads/sec from pagefile.sys (the response time seems quite slow reading from that file too - >500ms vs 0ms for all other I/O).  It doesn't have specialized hardware, but as I've said, most of the time it's fine.  Very little else that would be using the same drive (as far as I'm aware).

Comment: It seems very odd that there should ever be high I/O to `pagefile.sys` if you indeed have plenty of RAM available...  you might just be hitting an I/O bottleneck limit for your particular environment as far as throughout of MSMQ.

Comment: Hmm, I don't see how it can MSMQ-related when, as I've said, while 1 instance of the exe is unable to process messages in a timely fashion, if a I start up a second one, it's able to do so just fine. At most it could have something to do with the MSMQ client library, that potentially screws up that one process.

Comment: I guess that [procmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) will show what the program does for 30 minutes delay.

Comment: I did try that when it happened once some months ago, and frankly I've forgotten what I observed now - it was nothing particularly revealing, but other observations of perfmon counters etc. indicated some sort of garbage collection issue.  I had tweaked a few things that seemed to prevent that occurring (including gcServer enabled="true"), but now it's resurfaced again the other day during some particularly heavy usage.

Comment: Still no solution here unfortunately...

Comment: I would suggest using Process Explorer from Microsoft/SysInternals during the stale period. I guess it would be helpful to see what is going on in "Performance" and "Threads" tabs. The latest version of Process Explorer allows you to walk mixed mode call stacks (managed/unmanaged) and that could give you hints why your app is slow.

Comment: I've done that but the only really odd thing I'm seeing is that it says GC % time is 54%, and that using process monitor for a good 30 minutes the only operation it was performing was ReadFile (and only from pagefile and from core .NET assemblies). It's finally started to perform other operations that indicate at least some of my code is running, but I'm still not getting any SQL requests out of it, for example, and one thread sits in a loop doing them every second.

Comment: Is it possible that your application is leaking handles to unmanaged resources anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

Page faults in task manager mean the hits to the page file on the disk, which defaults to 1.5 times the amount of RAM you have installed. It isn't necessarily bad, it's just telling you where the data is.  You can turn off the paging file to see this number stay at 0.

Have you viewed the performance and counters of the products you depend on, like SQL Server or MSMQ?  Have you tried memtest86 to test your ram?

Comment: I seem to have it in this state again right now, and using the latest procmon the ONLY operation it is performing (and only against the pagefile and .NET assemblies) is ReadFile. No other Win32 calls else whatsoever, and it's been like that for over 30 minutes now. Bizarre.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  In my experience when you have intense applicactions that are "always on"; they should be placed in a Windows Service rather than a console app.

That being said it could be a problem with Garbage Collection.

Add this to your config file:

```
<runtime>
  <gcServer enabled="True"/>
</runtime>
```

You need to place it under the configuration node.

In my experience this will cause the app to have less PageFaults and a bigger Working Set.

There is no silver bullet. Without the code there is no way to know if your code is leaking memory; which could be another cause for excesive paging.